# Does google geocoding bounding box order important?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

When geocoding the same address with different order of bounding box the results are different.

when using bounding box order NE->SW returns a result

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=448+east+coast+road+marine+parade+district&sensor=false&bounds=1.549776,104.095882%7C1.151908,103.586786&language=en

but when using bounding box order: SW -> NE (which is the correct one according to google documentation) there are no results returned

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=448+east+coast+road+marine+parade+district&sensor=false&bounds=1.151908,103.586786%7C1.549776,104.095882&language=en

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the order is important. If you invert it, Bad Thins may happen.